# Use service from parent module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `api` module that defines a bunch of child modules `search`, `cart`, etc. The `api` module defines a bunch of functions that all the child modules can use, but I can not get this to work because it is giving me a `Circular Dependency` error.

```
var app = angular.module('api', [
    'api.search'
]);

app.service('api', function($cookies, $http, $rootScope, search){
    var data = {
        user: {
            token: null,
            userid: null
        },
        baseurl: 'http://website.com'
    };
    this.search = search;
});
```

Then for example in my search module I have this:

```
var app = angular.module('api.search', []);

app.service('search', function($http, api){
    this.lookup = function(domain){
        var baseurl = getData('baseurl');
        return $http({
            url: baseurl + '/domain/search',
            method: 'post',
            data: {domain: domain}
        });
    };
});
```

When I inject `api` like above, that is when I get the `Circular Dependency` error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep?p0=api%20%3C-%20search%20%3C-%20api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are injecting the search service into the api service and the api service into the search service.

```
app.service('api', function($cookies, $http, $rootScope, **search**){
app.service('search', function($http, **api**){
```

You have to choose one or the other.  Currently, it's simply re-injected into each other till an error is thrown.  You need to resolve only one of the services:

```
app.service('api', function($cookies, $http, $rootScope){
app.service('search', function($http, **api**){
```

Comment: It looks like the reason was because I was doing `this.search = search` in `api`